# How to traverse the list view column

Tags: c#

How to traverse the list view column so that we can check whether item in the list view column already exist or not and if it exist then change the item .

for example i have a list view with (quantity and item) and i want to check if the newly added item already exist in the list view then only change the quantity to quantity ++ rather then adding new item.

```c
string[] saLvwItem = new string[4];
saLvwItem[0] = a.ToString();
saLvwItem[1] = r["ItemNumber"].ToString();
saLvwItem[2] = r["ItemName"].ToString();
saLvwItem[3] = r["Price"].ToString();

ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(saLvwItem);
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

all the values are coming from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to match on ItemName (columnIndex=2) and increase the ItemNumber (columnIndex=1), then this may work:

```
    private void InsertOrUpdateItem(ListView listView, string[] saLvwItem)
    {
        if (saLvwItem == null || saLvwItem.Length < 4)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool bFound = false;
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items)
        {
            if (lvi.SubItems[2].Text == saLvwItem[2])
            {
                // item already in list
                // increase the ItemNumber
                lvi.SubItems[1].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lvi.SubItems[1].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(saLvwItem[1])).ToString();
                bFound = true;
                break;
            }                
        }

        if (!bFound)
        {
            // item not found
            // create new item
            ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem(saLvwItem);
            listView.Items.Add(newItem);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That is a poor implementation, nobody should be required to traverse through list view items and set flags. This function is unfortunately trying to reinvent the wheel :(

Comment: @Beenish Khan - Most implementations of ListViews are awful :).  It's a lacking control.  OP would need to set lvi.Name=r["ItemName"].ToString(); to get ContainsKey to work. Even then, the ContainsKey() implementation will also iterate through the list so not much of a performance gain.

Comment: Even before performance, it's about writing code which is not needed. The first rule of development is "Don't write new code which is not needed since you are creating new bug opportunities."

Answer (score 0):

Use following code,

```
if(!lvi.ContainsKey(saLvwItem[1]))
{
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(saLvwItem[2]); //Or whatever value you want to show as name
   listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

}
```

Listview has a key-value setting for every item, so you can't set four properties. Your key should be unique and your name should be exactly what you want to display, you can make a name by concatinating 2 or more values.

Comment: saying listviewItem does not contains a definition of ContainsKey

Comment: Are we talking about the same control ? Please check and confirm, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.containskey.aspx

Comment: Yes we are on the same code but still it is not working.
i just want to know how to traverse  the list view columns and to update them through  if condition.

Comment: try if(!lvi.Items.ContainsKey(saLvwItem[1]))